# Connect to Postgres container via Jira container

Tags: postgresql, docker, jira, docker-for-windows

I made postgres container via `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.15
    container_name: some-postgres
    volumes:
      -  postgresql-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rw_dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=rw_dev
      - POSTGRES_DB=rw_development
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
    postgresql-volume:
      external: true
```

After inspection i see that it is in `devops_default` network.
I want to connect not via `docker-compose` Jira to this database, i tried:

```
docker run -v jiraVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira --name="jira" -d -p 8080:8080  --env ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rw_development --env ATL_JDBC_USER=rw_dev --env ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=rw_dev  --env ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver --env ATL_DB_TYPE=postgres72 --link some-postgres:some-postgres --network devops_default atlassian/jira-software
```

But i am not sure `localhost` is accurate?
Cause i run docker on `Windows` so i have `docker-for-windows VM`.

When I open `localhost:8080` i see:

```
Database: JIRA couldn't connect to your database
JIRA failed to establish a connection to your database.
This could be because:
Your database isn't running
The configuration of your dbconfig.xml file is incorrect (user, password, or database URL etc.)
There is a network issue between JIRA and your database (e.g. firewall, database doesn't allow remote access etc.)
```

I've tried also:

```
docker run -v jiraVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira --name="jira" -d -p 8080:8080  --env ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/rw_development --env ATL_JDBC_USER=rw_dev --env ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=rw_dev  --env ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver --env ATL_DB_TYPE=postgres72 --link some-postgres:some-postgres --network devops_default atlassian/jira-software
```

And got the same error.

**Update:**

```
docker logs jira

INFO:root:Generating /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/server.xml from template server.xml.j2
INFO:root:Generating /etc/container_id from template container_id.j2
INFO:root:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml exists; skipping.
INFO:root:User is currently root. Will change directory ownership to jira then downgrade permissions
INFO:root:Running Jira with command '/bin/su', arguments ['/bin/su', 'jira', '-c', '/opt/atlassian/jira/bin/start-jira.sh -fg']
executing as current user

                  `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+
                     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM
                     :sdMMMMMMMMMMM
                             MMMMMM
          `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
             MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
              :sMMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
                     MMMMMM    `UOJ
   `sMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
      :sdMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
             MMMMMM    `UOJ
             MMMMMM
             +MMMMM
              MMMMM
               `UOJ

      Atlassian Jira
      Version : 8.5.0


If you encounter issues starting or stopping JIRA, please see the Troubleshooting guide at https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/jadm-docs-085/Troubleshooting+installation

Using JIRA_HOME:       /var/atlassian/application-data/jira

Server startup logs are located in /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.722 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'proxyPort' to '' did not find a matching property.
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.42
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 4 2019 20:29:04 UTC
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.42.0
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.790 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.9.184-linuxkit
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk/jre
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_232-b09
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            AdoptOpenJDK
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/atlassian/jira
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/atlassian/jira
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms384m
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djira.home=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options=-fg
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira-gc-%t.log
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCDetails
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.799 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCCause
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.800 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/jira
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/jira
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.801 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.903 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.921 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 461 ms
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.938 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.938 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.42
06-Nov-2019 10:08:17.960 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/Catalina/localhost]
2019-11-06 10:08:20,927 localhost-startStop-1 INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraHomeStartupCheck] The jira.home directory '/var/atlassian/application-data/jira' is validated and locked for exclusive use by this instance.
2019-11-06 10:08:21,060 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]

    ****************
    JIRA starting...
    ****************

2019-11-06 10:08:21,157 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]

    ___ Environment _____________________________

         JIRA Build                                    : 8.5.0#805000-sha1:facbf8be6a56ed8ab71dea158b6e159962506101
         Build Date                                    : Fri Oct 18 00:00:00 GMT 2019
         JIRA Installation Type                        : Standalone
         Application Server                            : Apache Tomcat/8.5.42 - Servlet API 3.1
         Java Version                                  : 1.8.0_232 - AdoptOpenJDK
         Current Working Directory                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
         Maximum Allowable Memory                      : 1820MB
         Total Memory                                  : 656MB
         Free Memory                                   : 455MB
         Used Memory                                   : 201MB
         Memory Pool: Code Cache                       : Code Cache: init = 33554432(32768K) used = 9386560(9166K) committed = 33554432(32768K) max = 536870912(524288K)
         Memory Pool: Metaspace                        : Metaspace: init = 0(0K) used = 20512704(20031K) committed = 21102592(20608K) max = -1(-1K)
         Memory Pool: Compressed Class Space           : Compressed Class Space: init = 0(0K) used = 2344688(2289K) committed = 2490368(2432K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
         Memory Pool: PS Eden Space                    : PS Eden Space: init = 100663296(98304K) used = 184082824(179768K) committed = 402653184(393216K) max = 673710080(657920K)
         Memory Pool: PS Survivor Space                : PS Survivor Space: init = 16777216(16384K) used = 16754848(16362K) committed = 16777216(16384K) max = 16777216(16384K)
         Memory Pool: PS Old Gen                       : PS Old Gen: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 9571752(9347K) committed = 268435456(262144K) max = 1431830528(1398272K)
         JVM Input Arguments                           : -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms384m -Xmx2048m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true -Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Djira.home=/var/atlassian/application-data/jira -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options=-fg -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira-gc-%t.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCCause -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/jira -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/jira -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp
         Java Compatibility Information                : JIRA version = 8.5.0, Java Version = 1.8.0_232

    ___ Java System Properties _________________

         atlassian.plugins.startup.options             : -fg
         atlassian.standalone                          : JIRA
         awt.toolkit                                   : sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
         catalina.base                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
         catalina.home                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
         catalina.useNaming                            : true
         common.loader                                 : "${catalina.base}/lib",
                                                         "${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar",
                                                         "${catalina.home}/lib",
                                                         "${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
         file.encoding                                 : UTF-8
         file.encoding.pkg                             : sun.io
         ignore.endorsed.dirs                          :
         java.awt.graphicsenv                          : sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
         java.awt.headless                             : true
         java.awt.printerjob                           : sun.print.PSPrinterJob
         java.class.version                            : 52.0
         java.home                                     : /opt/java/openjdk/jre
         java.io.tmpdir                                : /opt/atlassian/jira/temp
         java.locale.providers                         : COMPAT
         java.naming.factory.initial                   : org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
         java.naming.factory.url.pkgs                  : org.apache.naming
         java.protocol.handler.pkgs                    : org.apache.catalina.webresources
         java.runtime.name                             : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
         java.runtime.version                          : 1.8.0_232-b09
         java.specification.name                       : Java Platform API Specification
         java.specification.vendor                     : Oracle Corporation
         java.specification.version                    : 1.8
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory : org.apache.catalina.startup.SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
         java.util.logging.config.file                 : /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties
         java.util.logging.manager                     : org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
         java.vendor                                   : AdoptOpenJDK
         java.vendor.url                               : http://java.oracle.com/
         java.vendor.url.bug                           : http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
         java.version                                  : 1.8.0_232
         java.vm.info                                  : mixed mode
         java.vm.name                                  : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
         java.vm.specification.name                    : Java Virtual Machine Specification
         java.vm.specification.vendor                  : Oracle Corporation
         java.vm.specification.version                 : 1.8
         java.vm.vendor                                : AdoptOpenJDK
         java.vm.version                               : 25.232-b09
         jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize                    : 2048
         jira.home                                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
         mail.mime.decodeparameters                    : true
         org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK : 0027
         org.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER : true
         org.dom4j.factory                             : com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory
         os.arch                                       : amd64
         os.name                                       : Linux
         os.version                                    : 4.9.184-linuxkit
         package.access                                : sun.,
                                                         org.apache.catalina.,
                                                         org.apache.coyote.,
                                                         org.apache.jasper.,
                                                         org.apache.tomcat.
         package.definition                            : sun.,
                                                         java.,
                                                         org.apache.catalina.,
                                                         org.apache.coyote.,
                                                         org.apache.jasper.,
                                                         org.apache.naming.,
                                                         org.apache.tomcat.
         server.loader                                 :
         shared.loader                                 :
         sun.arch.data.model                           : 64
         sun.boot.library.path                         : /opt/java/openjdk/jre/lib/amd64
         sun.cpu.endian                                : little
         sun.cpu.isalist                               :
         sun.io.unicode.encoding                       : UnicodeLittle
         sun.java.command                              : org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
         sun.java.launcher                             : SUN_STANDARD
         sun.jnu.encoding                              : UTF-8
         sun.management.compiler                       : HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
         sun.os.patch.level                            : unknown
         tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled      : true
         tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan : log4j-taglib*.jar,
                                                         log4j-web*.jar,
                                                         log4javascript*.jar,
                                                         slf4j-taglib*.jar
         tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip : annotations-api.jar,
                                                         ant-junit*.jar,
                                                         ant-launcher.jar,
                                                         ant.jar,
                                                         asm-*.jar,
                                                         aspectj*.jar,
                                                         bootstrap.jar,
                                                         catalina-ant.jar,
                                                         catalina-ha.jar,
                                                         catalina-jmx-remote.jar,
                                                         catalina-storeconfig.jar,
                                                         catalina-tribes.jar,
                                                         catalina-ws.jar,
                                                         catalina.jar,
                                                         cglib-*.jar,
                                                         cobertura-*.jar,
                                                         commons-beanutils*.jar,
                                                         commons-codec*.jar,
                                                         commons-collections*.jar,
                                                         commons-daemon.jar,
                                                         commons-dbcp*.jar,
                                                         commons-digester*.jar,
                                                         commons-fileupload*.jar,
                                                         commons-httpclient*.jar,
                                                         commons-io*.jar,
                                                         commons-lang*.jar,
                                                         commons-logging*.jar,
                                                         commons-math*.jar,
                                                         commons-pool*.jar,
                                                         dom4j-*.jar,
                                                         easymock-*.jar,
                                                         ecj-*.jar,
                                                         el-api.jar,
                                                         geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,
                                                         h2*.jar,
                                                         hamcrest-*.jar,
                                                         hibernate*.jar,
                                                         httpclient*.jar,
                                                         icu4j-*.jar,
                                                         jasper-el.jar,
                                                         jasper.jar,
                                                         jaspic-api.jar,
                                                         jaxb-*.jar,
                                                         jaxen-*.jar,
                                                         jdom-*.jar,
                                                         jetty-*.jar,
                                                         jmx-tools.jar,
                                                         jmx.jar,
                                                         jsp-api.jar,
                                                         jstl.jar,
                                                         jta*.jar,
                                                         junit-*.jar,
                                                         junit.jar,
                                                         log4j*.jar,
                                                         mail*.jar,
                                                         objenesis-*.jar,
                                                         oraclepki.jar,
                                                         oro-*.jar,
                                                         servlet-api-*.jar,
                                                         servlet-api.jar,
                                                         slf4j*.jar,
                                                         taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,
                                                         tagsoup-*.jar,
                                                         tomcat-api.jar,
                                                         tomcat-coyote.jar,
                                                         tomcat-dbcp.jar,
                                                         tomcat-i18n-*.jar,
                                                         tomcat-jdbc.jar,
                                                         tomcat-jni.jar,
                                                         tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,
                                                         tomcat-juli.jar,
                                                         tomcat-util-scan.jar,
                                                         tomcat-util.jar,
                                                         tomcat-websocket.jar,
                                                         tools.jar,
                                                         websocket-api.jar,
                                                         wsdl4j*.jar,
                                                         xercesImpl.jar,
                                                         xml-apis.jar,
                                                         xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,
                                                         xmlParserAPIs.jar,
                                                         xom-*.jar
         user.country                                  : US
         user.dir                                      : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
         user.home                                     : /var/atlassian/application-data/jira
         user.language                                 : en
         user.name                                     : jira
         user.timezone                                 : GMT

06-Nov-2019 10:08:21.443 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Nov-2019 10:08:21.452 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
06-Nov-2019 10:08:21.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3570 ms
2019-11-06 10:08:21,582 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-11-06 10:08:21,665 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.DatabaseConfigHandler] Trying to get encrypted password from xml and decrypt it
2019-11-06 10:08:21,678 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.DatabaseConfigHandler] Database password decryption not performed.
2019-11-06 10:08:21,933 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger] Running JIRA startup checks.
2019-11-06 10:08:21,934 JIRA-Bootstrap FATAL      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger] Startup check failed. JIRA will be locked.
2019-11-06 10:08:21,991 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.LauncherContextListener] Memory Usage:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Heap memory     :  Used:  228 MiB.  Committed:  913 MiB.  Max: 2023 MiB
      Non-heap memory :  Used:   39 MiB.  Committed:   63 MiB.  Max: 1536 MiB
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      TOTAL           :  Used:  267 MiB.  Committed:  976 MiB.  Max: 3559 MiB
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may change this  `localhost:5432` to `postgres:5432`  in your `ATL_JDBC_UR` since localhost refer to jira docker and you already setup a network beteen them

Comment: Do you mean putting there container name, so in my case `some-postgres`? If so i tested it and I have the same issue. The same if i use `postgres`.

Comment: No the service name should be there like I wrote it

Comment: I've got the same error. You can try it yourself. Note that i can access `DB` via `PGadmin` from localhost.

Comment: localhost for the continer refer to itself that will not work in your case

Comment: I've tried:
`docker run -v jiraVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira --name="jira" -d -p 8080:8080  --env ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/rw_development --env ATL
_JDBC_USER=rw_dev --env ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=rw_dev  --env ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver --env ATL_DB_TYPE=postgres72 --link some-postgres:some-postgres --link postgres:postgres --network devops_default atla
ssian/jira-software` result is the same

Comment: Jira failed before getting to DB settings, you may try to delete all volumes and images you have and try again

Comment: Cool - now it works. I've deleted Jira (volume+container) but left the docker image of it.

Answer (score 4):

You should change :

```
ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rw_development.
```

to :

```
ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/rw_development
```

Or 172.18.0.1

Comment: In my case it would be `172.18.0.1` and i can aquire this info from `docker network inspect devops_default`. Still i like the other answer better.

Comment: Actually they are the same, ip address gateway of container

Comment: But i prefer to not type hardcoded `ip` address but type service name. It's more like a `service` discovery.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add special characters to my password. Evidently numbers and letters is not enough.